# Incremental Numbers from list, Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in Excel that checks a list of non-numbers and returns a value for the sum of Incremental numbers

So if I have a list of Three items: Cups, Mugs, Glasses
It would return: 6 (1+2+3)

If I have eight items: Cups, Mugs, Glasses, Plates, Coasters, Chairs, Tables, Laptops
It would return: 36 (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)

I'm trying to do this so it returns the value in a single cell. Using =Counta, of course but after trying out a few different things I'm stuck. Any math experts out there?

Comment: At first glance it would seem that you would be better off with some sort of bitwise addition so if you had a total of 37 you would know that your list was comprised of *Cups, Glasses* and *Chairs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)? The formula is (n * (n + 1))/2, where n is the number of items.

Comment: Yep, that is all I wanted. I'm sure I could have goggled it easy if I only knew it was called "triangular numbers". Thank you.